# Can a Fairplay certificate be ECDSA?

Tags: security

All the examples I've seen for Fairplay streaming certificates are 1024 bit RSA, but unless I missed it, it doesn't actually mention that as a restriction in the documentation...

I'm approved for it, but don't want to try it without confirmation that it'll work since they will only issue one certificate :)

So... can I use an ECDSA certificate? (secp256k? is there any limit?) or... is there a good reason why people are using 1024 bit RSA certificates?

(Also... since Fairplay is only used with Apple devices, which all have built in device certificates themselves... when sending the certificate to the client, is there any way to encrypt it such that the user can't easily see the certificate? Ideally I could encrypt it with the user's device certificate, and therefore know for sure the request came from a genuine Apple device.)

Comment: Could you expand on why you would want to create a different type of certificate? - Maybe what you want to achieve can be reached through other means?

Comment: @jksoegaard mostly for consistency, also because the strength of 1024 bit RSA is debatable. if EC certificates aren't acceptable, is 2048 bit RSA at least?

Comment: No, you cannot use a 2048 bit RSA certificate. Why do you worry about the strength of the certificate? - Are you worried that others will impersonate you when streaming to clients?

Comment: @jksoegaard Isn't having the private key like 90% of the way to breaking the protection entirely? The other secret as far as I know is deterministic and calculated from the certificate. I mean... I don't think my site is a big enough target for that, just seeing if it was an option :)

Comment: No, it's not "90% of the way". I'm not exactly sure what kind of threat you're talking about here. The actual streamed video content is not encrypted with the keys used for the certificate.

Comment: @jksoegaard I mean, okay, it isn't directly encrypting the content, but given the private keys, you can easily derive the keys protecting the content... I haven't seen any forward secrecy so far, unless I missed it?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use 1024 bit RSA certificates. If you try to submit for example a 2048 bit certificate signing request to Apple, it will be denied.

In the Deployment Package you have received from Apple, it is detailed how to generate the correct type of certificate signing request for FairPlay Streaming.

Your suggestion about encrypting the certificate before sending to the client doesn't really make sense. In the process of creating the certificate, you will create a private key, a certificate signing request - and you'll have the certificate itself. The private key must be kept absolutely private. The signing request is shared with Apple. The certificate itself is meant to be public - it is by design exposed to clients when streaming so that the validity of the certificate can be checked by the client.

Comment: Ah, the example commands are 1024 bit, but beyond that it doesn't mention any restriction on keys. I wanted to encrypt the certificate to keep my full name private, I figured if it was encrypted with the user's device certificate, then the user's device could still decrypt + verify it, but the user themselves couldn't.

Comment: I know it doesn't mention restrictions - I'm telling you what the restrictions are. You can try them out in practice, as I describe in the answer. You'll find that you can't upload a CSR based on for example a 2048 bit key.

Comment: Your idea of encrypting your certificate with another certificate (you can't really encrypt with a certificate, so I'm assuming you mean the public key) - won't work in practice. How would access the private key on the receiving end in order to decrypt the data. Also - it sounds quite suspect that you do not want anyone to know your name (?)

Comment: I think it's done via T2 chip, secure enclave, or authentication processor usually? It's used for MFi auth, apple pay, esim provisioning, other DRM systems... I don't usually share my *full legal* name publicly online, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I know what the T2 chip is used for ;-) I'm just saying that you cannot just access the private key on the receiving end of a video stream to encrypt or decrypt things for your private purpose. If you're issued certificates to be used for FairPlay streaming, it sounds reasonable that your identity could be verified.

Comment: Yeah, Apple has my full information, which is fine... I was hoping to limit the information available to the random strangers visiting my websites. The other DRM systems (Widevine etc) work exactly like that (private key in client hardware), which is why I asked. regardless, thanks for the help

Comment: Why not register a company and let that the be entity in the certificate?

Comment: i did consider that option (but mostly because the MS DRM cert required it), it's just a lot of extra work and i'd have to discuss with our lawyer. and now i'm wondering if after all's said and done, that just buying an existing on-prem server might've been cheaper...